# CSS Stylesheet not Working

Tags: php, html, css

I have an external CSS stylesheet, but for some reason the images are not loading.
Here is the source code at which i link to `style.css`.

```
<?
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if(!isset($_POST['rules'])){
                        $error = "Must read rules at spawn.";
                } else if(isset($_POST['grief'])){
                        $error = "We don't normally allow griefers. Your not allowed on our server unless you ask an Admin.";
                        $_SESSION['banned']=true;
                } else if(!isset($_POST['reg'])){
                        $error = "We prefer regular players.";
                } else if(empty($_POST['username'])){
                        $error = "The username field is empty?.";
                } else if($_POST['dumbtest'] != "6"){
                        $error = "Your too dumb to join this server.";
                } else {
                        include "comms.php";
                        addPlayerToExplorer($_POST['username']);
                        $error = "Welcome to SurviveEquestria, if everything went OK your now a Builder!";
                }
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>| Home</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

And theres nothing special about the style.css, but it begins with:

```
body {
background-image:url(images/bg.jpg);
}

#container {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1000px;
}
```

All of my images are located in an images folder, so i believe it points to the right images.

Comment: Is the images folder in the same folder as the stylesheet? the code 'images/bg.jpg' will look for the images folder within the stylesheet folder. Try using absolute paths like - url(/images/bg.jpg);

Comment: Also, you have a grammatical error in your message about people being too dumb.

Comment: @SagarPatil They are all located in the same folder. So theres style.css, index.php, apply.php, and the images folder.

Comment: First test without the PHP code to see whether the problem relates to it. Then check e.g. with Firebug to see whether the style sheet file is even read by the browser. If problems remain, please post a URL or construct a fiddle that demonstrates the problem. Also specify which browser(s) you used for testing.

Comment: Right. So just use the absolute path - url(/images/bg.jpg).

Comment: could you specify the absolute path to the images folder?

Comment: Don't believe that the images point to the right locations, verify it! Use Chrome developer tools [F12] oder Firebug to check for errors. Simple and efficient.

Comment: Can you load the background image in your browser using `http://(domain)/images/bg.jpg`? Does that work?

Comment: @MrLister It says I am Forbidden or in other words I cannot access the images.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I removed the PHP and it still does not work. I also tryed all of the css changes with the / . .. and ""

Comment: May I also note everything works fine when its not live (on my computer), but when i upload it to my host, it doesn't work any more.

Comment: So the site is actually live now? Can you give us a link, so we can check? I promise not to use POST to send information to your site.

Comment: @MrLister I fixed it by pulling them out of the folder and removing the 'images/'. And its password protected.

Comment: @VinylScratch OK. But it might have been a simple permissions issue. I mean, this subfolder was in a folder that you could read from, right? So I guess the subfolder just had read access turned off. You could still check that. (Not that it matters now for this site, but maybe the issue pops up somewhere else in the future and you might have to know where to look.)

Answer (score 1):

Remember image url is relative to css file path and change path to 
background-image:url("images/bg.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: url(../images/bg.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

> have you checked your path, that is correct or  check the location of
>   both files on same place

Answer (score 0):

Since you comment that “everything works fine when its not live (on my computer), but when i upload it to my host, it doesn't work any more”, the problem is apparently in the process of uploading (maybe transferred the image in a wrong mode) or in the server-side settings. There’s not much more we can do to help you without any relevant information about server-side things.

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer a way to debug this particular issue and other CSS reference issues in the future. Open up your page and then activate your browser's developer tools. (CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome).

Go to the Elements tab. Navigate the DOM until you see the CSS Entry. The URL for the stylesheet will be a clickable hyperlink. Click it. See where the browser navigates you. this should give you an indication as to what the fix is. Maybe you are too deep in the folder structure, maybe you are too shallow. In any case, I solve 99% of my CSS reference issues this way.